# How does memory work in Javascript at a low level?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Okay, so whoever answers this will be my hero, because this has been driving me crazy for the past few days.

After doing a lot of research on how memory in Javascript works, I came upon this paragraph from Eloquent Javascript that I think makes sense but I want to confirm my understanding.

> Because properties only grasp their value, rather than contain it, objects and arrays are stored in the computer’s memory as sequences of bits holding the addresses—the place in memory—of their contents. So an array with another array inside of it consists of (at least) one memory region for the inner array, and another for the outer array, containing (among other things) a binary number that represents the position of the inner array.

I took C programming, and from my understanding a variable in its broadest sense is a named memory location that has an address and a value. Normally, when you store a primitive, the actual pattern of bits that makes up the primitive value (say 10 for the primitive value 2) is stored as the variable's value. From this paragraph and from other sources, I gathered that when a variable stores an object, it really stores a reference (address) of the object as its value. The part I'm having trouble with is where the actual value of the object is stored in memory (the thing that the reference stored in the variable points to), and how the object's value contains variables (properties) itself?

As an analogy to what I'm asking, say we have these lines of code, with each variable having the address marked. (Note, I realize these addresses probably aren't how the interpreter stores them, this is just an example)

```
// Address is 0xA
var number = 4; 
// Variable address is 0xB, say address of object is 0xC
var obj = {
    array: [1, 2, 3],
    literal: 3
};
```

After this code executes, the memory location with address 0xA should have 
100 as its value, and the memory location with address 0xB should have 
0xC as its value.

So my question is, does the object at location 0xC have its own set of variables that have their own values like number and obj do? The paragraph from the book leads me to think that the array property in the object would have another memory address as its value, and the bit pattern for 3 as the value of the property literal. If this is the case, then does memory in Javascript work by referencing other parts of memory, and "terminating" when it hits literal values? (as the reference to the array would lead to an object containing properties that all contain literals)

I realize that this is probably way too low level, but if someone could give me a useful way to think about it so I could move past it, I would very much appreciate it.

Also, as a side note, I was reading about garbage collection, and I was wondering if the term "freeing memory" meant marking memory locations as not being in use anymore so other information can be written to it, or if it had to do with destroying the actual values contained in those memory locations, or if it had to do with causing variable names to stop referencing memory addresses (locations), or some crazy combination of the three.

Comment: Have you tried looking at source code for the various JS engines to see how they each handle memory? I'm sure there will be differences among the various engines around

Comment: It can work in a variety of ways. You might want to take a stab at implementing an interpreter for a small language to get a feel for this. There is a lot of reference (see what u did there) material available.